# Python win32api.MessageBox

Tags: python

У меня следующая проблема. При запуске .py файла MessageBox создаётся без всяких проблем, однако при компиляции этого кода в .exe MessageBox не появляется. С чем это может быть связано?

P.S. MessageBox создаётся в отдельном процессе, созданном с помощью multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему использования win32api, после компиляции кода можно решить, добавив в импорты строчку `import pywintypes`

Если не поможет, как альтернативный вариант решения, можно использовать `MessageBox`, предоставляемый библиотекой **tkinter**.

**Пример использования:**

```
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

#Убираем маленькое пустое окошко, созданное tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

#окно с кнопкой "ОК"
mb.showerror(title='Заголовок окна', message='Текст в окне MessageBox')

#окно с кнопками "ДА"/"НЕТ"
askBox = mb.askyesno(title='Предупреждение', message='Вы уверены, что хотите сбросить счет?')

#Получение результата
if askBox == True:
    #действие, при нажатии "Да"
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.messagebox.html). Надеюсь помог :)